# Vue CLI / Webpack - passing config variables to the frontend

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-2, vue-cli

I am beginning to build an app with Vue.js and have set it up using `vue-cli` using the `webpack` template. I need to pass a few different values to the front-end application when I build the app (mainly the API endpoint and a public Stripe key)

For whatever reason, adding them to the config folder's files doesn't pass the values to the front-end, which is probably to be expected as they're only used for the build, not passing the values to the front-end. When I `console.log` the `process` and `process.env` values, it shows the `env` as empty.

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL
});
```

or

```
export default Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
```

Is there a way to enable me to set different config variables for the application to use based on the environment? For instance, if I want to hit `app.api` locally in development and `api.app.com` in production?

### Edit

This is my config/index.js file, which is just the standard provided file. (I've removed the comments)

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your config/index.js file look like?

Comment: Please see the edit, it's just the standard index.js file provided

Comment: Your `config/prod.env.js` and `config/dev.env.js` should be exporting objects containing the name and value of your environment variables. Is that true in your case?

Comment: yes and no, it's exporting the objects but they're not being passed through to the front-end, it seems like they're only used for the build process.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. These are front-end environmental variables accessible in any part of your webpack project (given that you haven't made any major configuration changes to the generated template). Does your `config/dev.env.js` look like this? https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/config/dev.env.js

Comment: Yeah, it looks exactly like that, and I've not touched the configuration, When I console.log process.env, it's an empty object, however, it builds correctly based on the NODE_ENV value.

Comment: It doesn't build based off of the NODE_ENV value, the NODE_ENV value is set based on which build process you run `npm run build` or `npm run dev`. Where are you calling `console.log`?

Comment: I've tried in my app.js file, I've tried inside the default 'home' component in the created / mounted method, there's nothing there each time though, it's always an empty object

Comment: I've voted to close my question because I started another fresh project and it worked.